# Fixing dataLabel position in pie charts Highcharts even when data is changing

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I want to create my own custom `data label` for `pie charts`.
My purpose is that one `data label` will always appear on the top and the other one 
on the bottom.

I used `formatter` option to return `data label` as `HTML` to give me control over it.
The problem is that Highchart is binding `data labels` to its corresponding `slice` in the `pie`, thus each time data is updated, `labels` that were arranged with `CSS` are no longer in their places.

How can I disable this binding between the `labels` and `pie chart slices`?!

[My Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/SRcKrjACCd9MxSxvtlJz?p=preview)

My JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    connectorWidth: 0,
                    connectorPadding: 0,
                    color: 'black',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    formatter: function() {
                      if (this.point.name === 'matched') {
                          return '<div class="donut_unmatched_legend">'
                                  + '<div class="unmatched_num_legend">' + this.y + '</div>'
                                  + '<div class="unmatched_txt_legend">' + this.point.name + '</div>'
                                  + '</div>';
                      } else if (this.point.name === 'unmatched') {
                          return '<div class="donut_matched_legend">'
                                  + '<div class="matched_num_legend">' + this.y + '</div>'
                                  + '<div class="matched_txt_legend">' + this.point.name + '</div>'
                                  + '</div>';
                      }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
          data: [{
                  name: 'matched',
                    y: 25
                }, {
                    name: 'unmatched',
                    y: 50,
                }],
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice to disable datalabels and use [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Renderer.text) which allows to add custom shapes.

Comment: Can you provide small example for binding the `data` `{name, y}` with `Renderer`?

Comment: But where these points should be? You can get positio of slice from svg (kept in series.point object) and then (if you have coordinates) use a renderer